# Generating a table of distances between points and edges of nearest polygons?

Tags: arcmap, polygon, point

I have two shapefiles, one of made up of country borders and one made up of points randomly dotted around an ocean.  How do I generate a table of all the distances between the points and the closest edge of a polygon?

So for each point I will have a distance to it's nearest polygon/country.

I've looked at generating a near table but found that I only got distances to one plate (for all the points).

Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Spatial Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) tool.

**Target Features:** Point features in the ocean.

**Join Features:** Border features.

**Output features:** Select the attributes you want to save save probably some ID value with the border feature.

**Join Operation:** JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE

**Match Option:** CLOSEST_GEODESIC

Your features sound like they are really far away so you probably want to use geodesic distances

Comment: That worked great but I have one question, what if my points are within the polygons too? Is there any way for me to get their distances as those are just being read as zero.

Comment: You could convert your polygons to lines then run the spatial join. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/polygon-to-line.htm